# Using CMake GLOB_RECURSE to find directories

Tags: cmake, glob

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── deps
    ├── eigen
    │   └── include
    │       ├── Eigen
    │       └── eigen.h
    └── osg
        ├── include
        │   └── Osg
        └── lib
            └── libosg.so
```

I am trying to get a maximum of the files I don't need to deploy my software, i.e. the libraries.
I tried to create a globbing expression that matches the `*.h` files and the `include` directories:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE
  FOUND_FILES
  LIST_DIRECTORIES true
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/*/include
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/*/*.h)
message(STATUS "Files are ${FOUND_FILES}")
```

However, for some reason, the variable `FOUND_FILES` contains `deps/osg/lib`. What did I not understand about the `GLOB_RECURSE` function?

```
- deps/eigen/include
- deps/eigen/include/eigen.h
- deps/osg/include
- deps/osg/lib
- deps/eigen/include
- deps/osg/include
- deps/osg/lib
```

Comment: You are requesting it. From the docs: By default GLOB_RECURSE omits directories from result list - setting LIST_DIRECTORIES to true adds directories to result list.

Comment: Yes but nothing in osg/lib matches the globing expression

Comment: Good point. Must have missed that, sorry for the noise.

Comment: Yes, `deps/*.h` is sufficient indeed.

Comment: I can reproduce with simple `mkdir -p ./source/deps/osg/{include,lib} ./source/deps/eigen/include` and `file(GLOB_RECURSE
  FOUND_FILES
  LIST_DIRECTORIES true
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/source/deps/*/include
)
foreach(i IN LISTS FOUND_FILES)
    message(STATUS "${i}")
endforeach()` cmake script.. :/

Comment: There was a typo in my code snippet, it's CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this could be a workaround:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE
    FOUND_FILES
    LIST_DIRECTORIES true
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/*/include
)
list(FILTER FOUND_FILES INCLUDE REGEX "^${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/.*/include$")
file(GLOB_RECURSE
    tmp
    ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/*/*.h
)
list(APPEND FOUND_FILES ${tmp})
```

I guess this is a bug when `GLOB_RECURSE` is used with `LIST_DIRECTORIES true` with an expression that has `*` not on the last entry in the path. Once a directory containing the matched entry is matched in [cmake:Glob.cxx#L404](https://gitlab.kitware.com/yrHeTaTeJlb/cmake/-/blob/deec3a3f06d341cfe0bef4e856b263eff347cc72/Source/kwsys/Glob.cxx#L404), next directories will be added recursively to the output unconditionally at [this add_file() in cmake Glob.cxx#L316](https://gitlab.kitware.com/yrHeTaTeJlb/cmake/-/blob/deec3a3f06d341cfe0bef4e856b263eff347cc72/Source/kwsys/Glob.cxx#L316). So once a `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/*` directory has a `include` directory or file inside it, all directories recursively from `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/` are added to the output. Files are not added, as they are checked against the regex at [cmake Glob.cxx:#L326](https://gitlab.kitware.com/yrHeTaTeJlb/cmake/-/blob/deec3a3f06d341cfe0bef4e856b263eff347cc72/Source/kwsys/Glob.cxx#L326).

Comment: This does not work to find lower include directories. It doesn't really respond my question, however it suits my needs. I'm not sure if I should mark an answer as accepted.

Comment: Ooooch, right, because for example `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/a/b/include` will not be found : / So post filtering is an option. Edited the answer with a `list(FILTER REGEX`

Answer (score 2):

It appears that CMake drops the last component of the globbing expression when using `GLOB_RECURSE` to filter directories. This is why CMake does not filter further for the `include` directory in your example. This may be a bug in the CMake `GLOB_RECURSE` implementation for directories, or an oversight in the CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob-recurse).

**EDIT:** Solution 1 (does not work):

You can instead *simulate* recursion using the globbing pattern itself. Use CMake's `GLOB` instead, and use `**` in the globbing pattern to match on anything with one or more characters between `deps/` and `/include`:

```
file(GLOB
  FOUND_FILES
  LIST_DIRECTORIES true
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/**/include
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/deps/**/*.h)
)
message(STATUS "Files are ${FOUND_FILES}")
```

Solution 2 (ugly):

You could manually add the levels of directories for CMake to search for `include` folders:

```
file(GLOB
  FOUND_FILES
  LIST_DIRECTORIES true
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/*/include
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/*/*/include
  ...
)
```

However, this is not a very scalable solution.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that CMake doesn't support the `**` globbing pattern, and thus does not match the `*.h` and `include` directories two directories under deps.

Comment: "The globbing pattern used with `GLOB_RECURSE` appears to match any directory after the asterisk (`*`) in the pattern, and will not filter further for the `include` directory" - It seems that CMake simply drops the **last path component** of the globbing expression when search directories, whenever it contains asterisk or not. E.g., this globbing expression `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/NonExistentFile` will "match" to all *directories* under `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/` but to none *files*. A funny behavior indeed.

Comment: @Hugal31 You are correct; CMake doesn't appear to support the `**` globbing pattern. I added a potential workaround to my response, but it isn't very portable. There is almost certainly a more robust solution (perhaps, something using `GLOB` to collect the directory list, then using regex to filter it down to those ending in `/include`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Good catch! I modified the response to reflect your observations. Thanks